# Novel about a spider bite after which one can't lie anymore and doesn't need to sleep. Some vampires could be there, too

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this novel in German perhaps 15 years ago. Could be that the title contained the word "Sterne" ("stars"). But I'm not sure about this.

It was about a spider bite after which one can't lie anymore and doesn't need to sleep. Some vampires could be there, too.

Comment: As I didn't link you on your previous question you might want to look at our [story id guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, can you remember any plot elements or small bits of the story rather than just the outline here? Every little thing can help us identify this for you.

Comment: What is it with you and spider-related characters? :P

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I know, this isn't much information. But I don't remember much more. I hoped that the "can't lie anymore" spider bite is quite unique and might help to identify the story.

Comment: @Jenayah: Actually, I find spiders rather creepy. So that's perhaps why I forgot about the stories :-)